# Is there a way for java to get android pending OS update?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a method in java that returns if Android OS has a pending update.
I've read in AndroidDeveloper that it's possible by creating a DPC that installs "work profile" on the device. But is there a way to avoid that and get it via java?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/system-updates#check-updates) section inside the android developer docs describing this process using the `DevicePolicyManager` or see the below snippet from the page:

```java
SystemUpdateInfo updateInfo = dpm.getPendingSystemUpdate(adminName);
if (updateInfo != null) {
  Long firstAvailable = updateInfo.getReceivedTime();
  Log.i(TAG, "Update first available: " + new Date(firstAvailable));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I saw, you need to install another profile on your device, so you become the owner of it and as an owner you can check if there is a pending update. I've wondered if there is a way to do it without installing the profile.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or any from log output when trying to access the system information from a non-owner account?